# Set shipping settings programmatically in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

I work on Wordpress plugin to administrate woocommerce via API. and i try to set the shipping cost.
I can to add the area and specify the shipping method with the following code:

```
$new_zone_shipping  =   new WC_Shipping_Zone();
$new_zone_shipping  ->  set_zone_name("Giza");
$new_zone_shipping  ->  add_location('EG:EGGZ', 'state');
$new_zone_shipping  ->  add_shipping_method('flat_rate');
$new_zone_shipping  ->  save();
```

now i use for flat_rate only.
Possible simple method for fixing fixed cost?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem after searching on WordPress databases.

The `WC_Shipping_Zone` method `add_shipping_method()` returns the shipping method instance ID .

This instance ID is grabbed in the `wp_woocommerce_shipping_zones` table and used in `option_name` column on `wp_options` database table like  `woocommerce_flat_rate_1_settings`,
where `flat_rate` is the shipping method Id *(slug)* and **`1`** is the shipping method instance Id.

So the working code is:

```
$zone_name     = 'Giza';
$country_state = 'EG:EGGZ';
$method_id     = 'flat_rate';
$shipping_cost = 22;

$new_zone_shipping = new WC_Shipping_Zone();
$new_zone_shipping->set_zone_name( $zone_name );
$new_zone_shipping->add_location( $country_state, 'state' );

$instance_id = $new_zone_shipping->add_shipping_method( $method_id );

$new_zone_shipping->save();

add_option( 'woocommerce_'. $method_id .'_'. $instance_id .'_settings', array(
    'title'      => $method_id,
    'tax_status' => 'taxable',
    'cost'       => $cost
),'' , 'yes' );
```

**Important note:** Don't forget to sanitize all data values as this is just a simple example.